# error when start new project in visual studio 2010

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, deployment, error, database

I am a new administrator to a SharePoint farm and I want to start developing **web-part**s for our sites.

In our company we have installed **SharePoint 2010** on **Windows Server 2008 R2.**

And we have installed **Microsoft visual studio 2010** on that server.

We also have **Microsoft SQL server management studio** installed in the same server.
In my computer (**Windows 7 professional**), I have used **remote desktop connection** to access that server.

From **SharePoint central administration**, I have created new application, new site collection and new site.

I started VS with admin rights.

From File => New => Project =>Visual basic => SharePoint =>2010 => Empty SharePoint project => ok

Then I got a dialog box asking me to enter the local site that I want to use for debugging. 
I entered "http://sharepoint:21029/team1/"

I chose **deploy as a farm solution** checkbox.

Click Validate.

The problem is:

When I click **Validate**, I get the following error:

**Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: "http://sharepoint:21029/team1/"  Make sure that the Site URL is valid, that the SharePoint site is running on the local computer, and that the current user as the necessary permissions to access the site.**

---

I made a lot of searches on the internet and finally I found this link:

http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/19/resolving-vs-2010-solution-deployment-issues-for-sharepoint-2010-projects/

When I tried to solve my problem as described in the previous link, I could not find the following databases:

**SharePoint_Config**

**SharePoint_AdminContent_[guid]**

**SharePoint Site Content DB**

Why I could not find the databases in the SQL Management Studio?
And why I get the error?

I want to start developing web-parts in visual studio... Any help please!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution finally :)

I found this critical in Event Viewer:

SQL database log in for 'SharePoint_Config' on instance 'sharepoint' failed.

I did the following steps and it solves my issue and I can now connect visual studio to my SharePoint site successfully ^_^

---

**Grant correct permissions to the database access account**

**To resolve this issue, assign the database access account and then verify that the account has correct permission in SQL Server.**

**To assign the database access account:**

1. On the Central Administration Web page, on the Quick Launch, click
   Security, and in the General Security section click Configure
   service accounts.
2. In the Credential Management section, in the upper drop-down list
   click the correct Web application pool for your Web application.
3. In the Select an account for this component drop-down list, click
   the domain account with which you want to associate this Web
   application pool, or click Register new managed account to associate
   a new domain account with this application pool.
4. Click OK to save changes.

---

Thank you all

Comment: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513059(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: "Grant correct permissions to the database access account" -> Can you tell me what is the correct permission?  Is it sysadmin?

Answer (score 1):

The databases will exist, you're just looking in the wrong place, or they might be named something different or something unique to your environment. The Site Content DB is normally WSS_Content_[GUID]. The fact that you were able to create the site in Central Admin confirms this.

Make sure you can visit the site in the browser, and that you have access to it. Then, also make sure you are using Visual Studio as the same user that has access to the site.

If /team1/ is a subsite, try telling visual studio to go to the root (or top-level site) instead.

Comment: Yes I can visit the site in the browser ,I am using the same user in VS and the same error happen when I use the root site collection instead of team1. What can I do !!

Comment: Try opening the Visual Studio with Run as Administrator! About the databases, can you look if an instance named SharePoint is installed on your database server! When you install SharePoint Foundation with single server, it installs a new instance named `SQL-SERVER-NAME\SharePoint`...

Comment: yes I started VS with admin rights. In our environment we have SharePoint server not foundation version. When I run Microsoft server Management studio, a dialog box appears as the following: Server type: Database engine, Server name: SHAREPOINT\SQLEXPRESS and Authentication: windows authentication.

Comment: Actually, I only have System databases (master, model, msdb, tempdb). no more !

Comment: In Central Admin, go to Applicaton Management -> Manage Content Databases, this will tell you where (what server + what instance) they are.